# Pip Package: installs properly but cannot use any of its classes or methods even though it imports

Tags: python, pip

I am implementing a package that is to be installed via pip. It properly installs, and the library imports without errors, but I cannot seem to access any of the helper methods or classes in it.

I do not know how to go about debugging this. Here is the file structure:

data commons

-requirements.txt

-setup.py

-CHANGELOG

-dist

-MANIFEST

-README

--data_commons

---__init__.py

---postgres_conn.py

---redshift_conn.py

---url_helpers.py

---jobs

----__init__.py

----some_job.py

My current setup.py reads:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='data_commons',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='me',
    author_email='me@me.com',
    packages=['data_commons'],
    scripts=[],
    url='url',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='Useful Helpers',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    install_requires=[
        'boto==2.32.1',
        'psycopg2==2.5.3',
        'wsgiref==0.1.2',
    ],
)
```

Comment: Can you format the file tree properly and then paste a snippet of the exact error you see when you try to work with your library? My guess is that you have some imports messed up and the modules are not being imported into the right namespaces.

Comment: My brain is insisting that something is missing with that distutils setup, but is refusing to tell me what.  That said, have you tried just using setuptools and the find_packages callable it provides?

Comment: Also, note: This is not a pip issue, its a distutils issue, and it is most defiantly not installing properly

Comment: I will try that now @Tritium21